# Formatting posts with the Slack api

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to create Posts with `botkit` using the Slack api, but I can't find any documentation on how to format a `Post` file in Slack.

```
bot.api.files.upload({
    content: "# Heading",
    filename: "test.md",
    filetype: "post",
    channels: "random"
});
```

Markdown formatting doesn't work for this, is there any syntax to formatting Slack Posts?

Trying with HTML the response from the created file is like this:

```
<document><p>&lt;document&gt;&lt;h1&gt;H1&lt;\/h1&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;h2&gt;H2&lt;\/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;h3&gt;H3&lt;\/h3&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Text &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;\/i&gt; &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;\/b&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;<a href=\"http:\/\/www.slack.com%22%3Elink%3C\/a%3E\">http:\/\/www.slack.com&quot;&gt;link&lt;\/a&gt;<\/a> &lt;u&gt;underline&lt;\/u&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strike&gt;strikethrough&lt;\/strike&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;code&gt;Code Block;&lt;\/code&gt;&lt;\/p&gt;&lt;\/document&gt;<\/p><\/document>
```

so it's escaping html tags.

Comment: It's just using the CEF -- it may be as simple as formatting the post in HTML.

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't add any format, just displays the HTML tags as text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posts support [markdown](https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown-quick-reference/) formatting.

E.g., try setting the following content:

```
# A Post Header

### Subheading

An image? ![Funny](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4jlx3aktZVFKAkaNB7fvy67BFQuaO3HedVQ6VIXeR5OLnfbOOEbrcp-G4)

[A link to google](https://www.google.com)

* A list item
* Another list item

`a code block`
```

You then post with `filetype="post"`, and get the following:

[image]

I tested and slack appears to support **most** markdown features but not all.  Make sure to test your formatting!

Comment: Weird, I tested markdown when I asked this question and it was not working, maybe I missed something, I'll give it a second try

Comment: Aha, It is working with markdown now, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: My guess is they're still actively working on it and a month ago it didn't actually work =).  filetype=post isn't even documented so my guess is we can expect more changes to come!

Comment: filetype=post is now documented https://api.slack.com/types/file#file_types