# How can I create Hyperlinks in slack snippet

Tags: slack, slack-api

How does one create hyperlinks in slack snippets?

I am trying to upload a snippet through WEB API, but the Hyperlinks that am providing doesn't work and it posts as normal text. I can create hyperlinks in attachments, but I want to do the same with snippets.

Comment: From the description on https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204145658-Create-a-snippet, it sounds like snippets are plaintext only and don't respect formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippets are plain text and can not contain formatted text. If you want to upload a text file with hyperlinks you need to create a `post`.

Use [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) with the following minimum parameters:

- `token`: your token
- `content`: string with the content of you file via this POST variable
- `filetype`: `post`
- `channel`: ID of channels to share directly

Add additional parameters as needed, but don't use the `file` parameter.

Your file can be a standard text file. URLs will be automatically converted.

Example:

```
This is a test file! Hyperlink: https://www.google.de/
```

This is how it looks in Slack:
[image]

Comment: Hyperlinks with text using <link|text> don't seem to work in Posts / files, but I can edit them afterwards to add embedded links on text. Do you know what syntax to embed links on text in posts?

Comment: yes, you have to use markdown formatting. check out this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38969853/4379151